# Function sweep() in R error message

Tags: r

With these data:

```
set.seed(1); n = 50; x1 = rnorm(n, 10, 3); x2 = rnorm(n, 15, 3); x3 = rnorm(n, 20, 3)
dataframe = data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
```

I wanted to reproduce the centering (without scaling) achieved with:

```
centered = scale(dataframe, scale=F)
```

using the sweep function. But I get this error message:

```
sweep(dataframe, 2, mean, "-")
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

I have tried changing the data frame format to a matrix without success with the same error message.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mean` is a function name and by using that in the `sweep` along with `-` implies there are two functions.  However, according to `?sweep`, the usage is

> sweep(x, MARGIN, STATS, FUN = "-", check.margin = TRUE, ...)

So, the `mean` could be possibly the "STATS".  It could be a object name of a vector of column means (though not clear from the OP's post).  If we provide the "STATS" as the column mean (`colMeans(dataframe)`), it will do the subtraction (`-`) of each column of 'dataframe' by the corresponding value from the vector of column means i.e.

```
res <- sweep(dataframe, 2, colMeans(dataframe), "-")
head(res, 2)
#         x1         x2         x3
#1 -2.1807063  0.8423383 -1.4036437
#2  0.2495851 -2.1880585  0.5838039

head(centered, 2)
#            x1         x2         x3
#[1,] -2.1807063  0.8423383 -1.4036437
#[2,]  0.2495851 -2.1880585  0.5838039
```

---

Here is another example that shows how the `sweep` works by specifying the `MARGIN` as 2.  We create a `vector` ('v1') with `length` equal to the number of columns of the 'data.frame' ('d1')

```
 v1 <- 1:3
 d1 <- data.frame(Col1 = 1:5, Col2= 6:10, Col3 = 11:15)
 sweep(d1, 2, v1, "-")
 #  Col1 Col2 Col3
 #1    0    4    8
 #2    1    5    9
 #3    2    6   10
 #4    3    7   11
 #5    4    8   12
```

It does the `-` between the first column of 'd1' with corresponding element of 'v1', 2nd column with 2nd element of 'v1' and so on..  However, it cannot take another function to do some operation on the same dataset and return that as "STATS" vector to perform the `FUN` between the dataset and transformed one unless we do that explicitly as shown in the solution earlier.

```
sweep(d1, 2, mean, "-")
#Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
#cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

#### data

```
dataframe <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is the wrinkle: In the function call, the "2" means do the following columnwise. So I don't understand (it's about the concept - the practical solution is clear) why you would have to reiterate this by calling `colMeans()` in the next entry. `mean()` or `mean(dataframe)` would make sense - the program already knows that it's supposed to do it columnwise.

Comment: @AntoniParellada  The `2` means to do that columnwise, that part you are right.  But, what it does columnwise, is on the `FUN` i.e. `-` for the data.frame and the vector of another dataset, not to do another round of columnwise on the original dataset.  Anyway, if you want the functionality in your mind to be executed, change the `sweep` source code and do it.

Comment: Of course. Consider it accepted. If and only if you have time, could you please explain in your answer the issue with the separate datasets perhaps with an example.

Comment: @AntoniParellada  I added an example.  Hope it helps